# Non-English characters are all broken in JSP file

Tags: jsp

I'm modifying a JSP file and all Japanese characters in it are not displayed like below.

```
<input type="submit" name="form" value="ç»é²"> <!-- MEMO æãã¯ãããã£ã¦ãããã<button name="form">ç»é²</button> 
<input type=button ãããªã®ã¯å­å¨ããªã-->
```

Is it able to recover them?

---

*I added more information:

1. editor: STS
2. encoding: UTF-8
3. The encoding is already UTF-8 for Japanese, so I haven' done anything.
4. more example:

header.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
```

loginForm.jsp

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/common/header.jsp"%>
<div align="center">
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/top" method="GET"> <!-- FIXME postÃ£ÂÂ«Ã¤Â¿Â®Ã¦Â­Â£ -->
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>ã¦ã¼ã¶ID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="userId" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ãã¹ã¯ã¼ã:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>

<input type="submit" value="ã­ã°ã¤ã³"/>
```

Comment: What editor are you using? What is the encoding of the JSP file (e.g. UTF-8)? Have you tried to switch the encoding in the editor?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I added more information.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I solved it by myself. I got a hint from your advice if I tried to switch the encoding or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

IT was JSP encoding trouble. There was no trouble in Java file.
So the solution is...

STS Menu -> Preference -> General -> Content Types
-> Text -> JSP -> default encoding -> write UTF-8 -> OK

and then we can see that broken characters have turned into their original appearance.

---

*references(Japanese):

http://proengineer.internous.co.jp/content/columnfeature/9147#section001
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/gnarl/20090317/1237290886